# "Outgoing Server Requires Authentication" behavior in .NET - server with unusual configuration

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, smtp

One of my users is trying to use a mail host that seems to have an unusual configuration and it has me stumped.

I *can not* get it to send out mail in my program or in Mozilla Thunderbird, but I *can* get it to work in Outlook. These are the settings they provide:

- Outgoing: smtpa.namechanged.net Port 25
- Requires a secure connection (SSL)
- Must select ‘Outgoing Server Requires Authentication’
- Do not select ‘Secure Password Authentication (SPA)’

I can ONLY get this to work in Outlook if I set "Use the following type of encrypted connection" to NONE (NOT to SSL or TLS!)... and have the check-box checked for "Outgoing Server Requires Authentication"

Current relevant code (in vb.net... You can answer in C# tho!):

```
Dim SmtpClient As New SmtpClient()
SmtpClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(mESettings.Username, mESettings.Password)
SmtpClient.Port = mESettings.Server.Port
SmtpClient.Host = mESettings.Server.Host
SmtpClient.EnableSsl = mESettings.Server.UseSSL = SSLType.Explicit_SSL
SmtpClient.Send(Mail)
```

If I use No SSL here I get the error "Authentication failed." With SSL I get "Server does not support secure connections."

**My question is: I cannot figure out what combination of properties on .NET's SmtpClient class (or CDO, if needed) mirrors "Outgoing Server Requires Authentication" with no SSL.  How do I provide this in .NET?**